# Android emulator can't get API data through web site

Tags: javascript, android, emulation

I have frontend and backend ready and working on localhost. I am displaying the frontend web site through the Android emulator:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webview.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:4200/mobile");

    }
}
```

[image]

The problem is that emulator can't get the data from database or send request to API to receive the data so that it's not displayed. How it looks on a web site:

[image]

Once again the problem is straight with emulator. I tried building the frontend in production mode with no success. This issue looks strange to me because I am just "retranslating" the working website. Maybe I should declare a special permission or something like that.

Android Studio Error:

[image]

Comment: I cannot see how there shall be an API involved. consider fixing these `JavaScript` errors, maybe?

Comment: @MartinZeitler api is provided to the website. I've mentioned it because the site is displayed without api methods on emulator. The frontend itself is displayed correctly. I don't know how should I fix js errors because the js works correctly on desktop browser but not emulators one. Also they are displayed quite weird but I'll put additional attention on it, thanks